# PySpark unit tests with large dataset on Databricks platform

Tags: python, unit-testing, pyspark, large-data, databricks

I would like to ask you - experts - about the best approach to work with the really large dataset for the unit tests of the functions which are using PySpark (written in Python of course).

**Ideal World:**

Ideally is to keep the input and output/expected data for the tests very closely to the tests. It is described in almost every tutorial and blogpost e.g. [here](https://dev.to/diogoaurelio/getting-started-with-spark-part-4----unit-testing-26a5)

```py
def test_amount_spent_udf(spark_session: SparkSession) -> None:
    input_df = spark_session.createDataFrame([
        Row(customer_name="Geoffrey", date="2016-04-22", category="Foo", product_name="Bar", quantity=1, price=2.00),
    ])
    expected_result = 2.00

    result = amount_spent_udf(data=input_df)

    assert result.collect()[0].amount_spent == expected_result
```

In this situation, it is not a problem to add e.g. more rows for checking different cases. Everybody is happy and the unit tests are very simple to maintain and extend if needed.

**Real World:**

The problem appears when the amount bases on more columns than only `quantity` or `price`.
What about the situation when we have something like this:

```py
def test_amount_spent_udf(spark_session: SparkSession) -> None:
    input_df = spark_session.createDataFrame([
        Row(
            customer_name="Geoffrey",
            date="2016-04-22",
            category="Foo",
            product_name="Bar",
            quantity=1,
            price=2.00,
            used=True,
            method="online",
            shipping_price=4.00,
            global_discount=0.05,
            personal_discount=0.15,
        ),
    ])
    expected_result = 5.60

    result = amount_spent_udf(data=input_df)

    assert result.collect()[0].amount_spent == expected_result
```

As you can see, the result is different because the amount must be calculated with the usage of the additional fields like `global_discount`, `personal_discount` or even `shipping_price`.

Here, adding new rows is a little bit harder than in the previous example. Especially because of the limit of signs per line (120) and more columns which must be shown somehow.

**The problem:**

In our project, we have an even more complicated situation. We have the functions which are transforming the DataFrame which contains 30 columns into the DataFrame with 45 columns or calculate one value based on 15 other (*it is only the example*).

It is not a problem to prepare the data for the test for these functions but it is a very ugly and line-consuming code when we wanna put all the data inside the test (or even in the separate module).

The temporary solution which simplifies the data a little is to put them into the list of tuples:

```py
INPUT_DATA = [
    ("Geoffrey", "2016-04-22", "Foo", "Bar", 1, 2.00, True, "online", 4.00, 0.05, 0.15),
]
```

When the order of data is the same as the order of the schema's columns, it is possible to keep the data this way but this solution is not enough when the count of the columns is equal to 30

Putting data into e.g. CSV files is also not possible because it is not possible to import these files into the Databricks platform and run the tests there.

*Note: running the unit tests on the Databricks platform is important for us because it is the environment where the real code is working.*

I would like to get your opinion on that, maybe someone has the same problem and resolve it in the way which I didn't describe here or even I didn't think